# for loop integrated in the argument field of an if statement in c++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am working on solving a mathematical problem.
What I am trying to do is to have an if statement that compares variable n to a set of variables i 1 through 10. Is there any way to do it in c++?
here is what I am trying to do:

```
 int smallPos(int n){
     if (n%for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)==0) {
        return n;
      }
```

This is obviously wrong but is any way to get around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is this:

```
int smallPos(int n)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
    {
        if (n % i != 0) // check if n % i == 0, if not, then we shouldn't return n.
        { 
            return -1; // or whatever you want to return when not ALL the remainders are 0.
        }
    }

    return n; // If we get here then all the remainders were 0s.
}
```

Comment: Well, I can only return n if all of the values 1-10 result in zero remainder. That is if at least one of them does not result in zero remainder then n should not be returned.

Comment: Ooooh! i see, thats clever.
Thank you!

Comment: +1 for a legible answer, but see my answer for an optimized version.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to do this:

```
int smallPos(int n)
{
    return (n % 232792560 == 0) ? n : <sentinel value>; // sentinel_value is the value return if n does not meet requirements
    //232792560 is the first number for which n % a: a ∈ {1,2,3...10} This is faster than checking each of these values.
}
```